# How to edit code when debugging a 64 bit

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, x86, 64-bit

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Vb. I try to use edit-and-continue (edit the code while debugging), and get this exception:

"Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed"

And targeting the x86 platform, doesn't work.
 What can I do?  Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you seen JaredPar's response to this questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105292/how-do-i-enable-file-editing-in-visual-studios-debug-mode

Comment: No but "Edit and Continue" checked. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Edit + Continue in VS2012 is only supported for 32-bit code, as it has been since VS2005.

This will be changing soon, E+C for 64-bit managed code will be supported in VS2013.  Currently in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Continue is now officially available in Visual Studio 2013 for both 32-bit and 64-bit.