# Ask Visual Studio not to notify me after I change a source file while debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I frequently find it convenient to [edit source files while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105292/how-do-i-enable-file-editing-in-visual-studios-debug-mode). Whenever I do so, VS feels the need to give me a popup if I continue with the debugging session:

> The source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the file used to build the application being debugged.

I suppose they are concerned I might forget that I've made the change, then be confused as I step through the no-longer-accurate code. But that's silly. It is just as easy to forget that I've clicked through the popup. I really wish it wouldn't notify me.

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: Hi William, what's your VS version and the project type? Does this issue persists for all your solutions? If so, could you please share a detail step to reproduce it, thanks.

Comment: Meanwhile, uncheck Options-Debugging-General-Require source files to exactly match the original version and restart vs to have a test.