# Disable being able to edit code while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Recently when I've been debugging my application, I've been able to write code into C# files when the application isn't in the broken state. I've tried totally disabling the "Edit and Continue" setting in the visual studio options but that doesn't seem to be working.

What I'm expecting to happen is when I'm debugging and I type into a C# file, I want that popup that says "Changes are not allowed while the application is running" prompting me to put a breakpoint in my code to apply changes during runtime while the application is in the paused state. I'm not sure if this was a change that was introduced into the latest 2019 build or if there's something wrong with my options. Any ideas on this one would be great.

For reference, this is the popup that I want:

[image]

and these are my settings:

[image]

and proof of the functionality that I don't want

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug - I upvoted your VS feedback item too.

Comment: @Postlagerkarte thanks. Hopefully they get it sorted. Was mostly seeing if anyone else had a similar issue and knew of some kind of work-around.

Comment: According to their feedback It's a feature not a bug. Interesting :) I post it as an answer so others can find it here in case the stumble upon this aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the VS Team this works as designed:

> This behavior you described is expected for Visual Studio 16.3. We
>   went through several changes on Edit and Continue and now allow
>   editing the code while the application is running. Any errors or
>   warnings regarding your changes will show up at the Error List Window.
>   In order to apply these changes, you simply have to be on a break
>   state (e.g. break all or stop on a breakpoint) and continue from
>   there.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/768979/able-to-type-while-debugging.html

Answer (score -2):

**Tools** > **Options** > **Debugging** > **General**, select **Edit and Continue** in the right pane.

Comment: That does not stop me from typing in the code editor while debugging.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5673006/7272863
If you are on Win 7: Turn off IntelliTrace: If you are on Win 10, IT is compatible with Edit & Continue