# ASP.NET Debugging problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, 64-bit, edit-and-continue

I'm building web sites in Visual Studio 2010.
I recently upgraded to a new dev machine running windows 7 64-bit. 
Now, when I make a change to a webpage, I have to stop debugging, kill cassini, and start debugging again before the new code takes effect. I didn't have this problem in XP.

Things I've tried...

- compilation debug="true" in config file
- options->Debugging->Edit and Continue is enabled

I'm not sure if this follows under dynamic compilation or Edit and Continue - any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

One of my colleagues is not having this problem. He has an identical setup to me, using the same project, same build configuration (Any CPU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this was my fault... I had experienced the dreaded "network BIOS command limit has been reached" issue. I found a post that recommended doing a regedit hack "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode = 1", well this basically turns off File Change Notifications. Changing this value to 2, and applying the changes recommended in knowledge base 810886 fixed both problems.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is due to the change from a 32 bit os to a 64 bit os.  The ability to change code while the application is running is unique to 32 bit code.  In a 64 bit executable, this capability is removed.

This is known as "Edit and Continue".  See this question for a good explanation of why this won't work on a 64bit executable:

[Why doesn't Edit and Continue work on the x64 CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955922/why-doesnt-edit-and-continue-work-on-the-x64-clr)

**EDIT:** Clarification:

This isn't an issue with the OS, but rather the build of your code.  If you have your build configuration set to "Any CPU", it will run under the architecture of your machine (x64 in your case).  You should be able to force this to x86 and be able to use Edit and Continue.

Comment: I've read this too, but, in my configuration manager dialog, I can't seem to figure out how to change the configuration of my website project to anything but "Debug/Any CPU". I have a couple "library" code projects in the same solution - I can change the platform to x86 on those, but I only have the one option for the website. In addition, the developer in the next cube, same project/vs/win7/machine is able to edit and continue! His build configuration is set to Any CPU!

Comment: If you go to `Build > Configuration Manager` in Visual Studio, you can change the build configuration on a project-by-project basis.  If you don't see the option for x86 in the platform dropdown, choose "New". I'm not guaranteeing that changing the platform to x86 will enable Edit and Continue, but its a good place to start.

Comment: In the configuration manager, my 'website' project has no option besides "Any CPU". There is no "New" option. I know what you're talking about - I do have these options for the other projects in the solution - just not the website itself. Is this because it's a website as opposed to a "web application"?

Comment: Yeah.  I just tested that.  I got the option when I created a web application project, but not when I created a web site.

Answer (score 2):

64-bit apps can't be dynamically modified during debugging. To be able to do that you'll need to change your your build target 'x86'. Easy!

Just change it back (if you really need 64-bit assemblies).