# Is there a way to debug with Petrel 2012.1 64-bit?

Tags: ocean, petrel

When starting the debugger, Visual Studio just hangs for about 20 seconds, then terminates the debugging session, without any warning.

The 32-bit version works fine, but is no good if our plugin uses 64-bit native code from a third party.

As a developer, I'm sticking with Petrel 2012.1 on my workstation for the time being - might the issue be fixed in a later release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug but a feature – the license protection mechanism. But you can attach your debugger to Petrel 2012.1 64 bit when Petrel's UI is visible, the initial steps only are protected from debugging.

Comment: Thanks - I should have tried attaching - apologies for my impatience :-)

Answer (score 0):

But of course you would still need to use 32-bit version of Petrel if you want edit-and-continue while debugging: [Why doesn't Edit and Continue work on the x64 CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955922/why-doesnt-edit-and-continue-work-on-the-x64-clr)